# Migrating self referencing foreign key issue

Tags: database, laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration, lumen

I am using Laravel migrations for Lumen project where I have tree type table: |id|name|parent_id.  but I need to use foreign-keys. I am just interested is this solution below a good one? or are there any better solutions?

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string("name");
        $table->integer("parent_id")->unsigned()->nullable();

    }); 
    Schema::table('services', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('services')
                                        ->onDelete("RESTRICT")
                                        ->onUpdate("CASCADE");
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You don't need `Schema::table()`, you can move `$table->foreign()` to `Schema::create()`.

Comment: I hate foreign keys, but this is even worse!

Comment: Looks good to me. Could you explain why you have concerns over whether it might not be a good solution?